# elementary fails to boot installations media, and fails to boot install

Tags: system-installation

I am trying to install elementary OS Freya on my laptop and I've tried a thousand programs and bootable USBs and nothing, these are the specs:

```
-Computer-
Processor: 2x AMD Turion (tm) 64 X2 Mobile Technology TL-58
Memory: 1789MB (1157MB used)
Operating System: Zorin 11
Date / Time: Fri 11 Mar 2016 11:57:12 CET
-Display-
Resolution: 1280x800 pixels
OpenGL Renderer: Unknown
X11 Vendor: The X.Org Foundation
-Multimedia-
Audio Adapter: HDA-Intel - HDA ATI SB
-input Devices-
 Power Button
 lid Switch
 Sleep Button
 Power Button
 Translated AT September 2 keyboard
 Video Bus
 SynPS / 2 Synaptics TouchPad
 Acer BMA150 accelerometer
 Logitech USB Laser Mouse
 HDA ATI SB Mic
 HDA ATI SB Line
 HDA ATI SB Front Headphone
 Acer CrystalEye webcam
-Printers-
No printers found
-scsi Disks-
Hitachi ATA HTS54161
HL-DT-ST DVD-RAM GSA-T20N
```

Since the USB booteable stays fixed on the screen with the "e" logo and stay here forever, if I enter in the initial menu and test Live version, only works after giving enough times Esc key, from there I try to install and all it seems to work well in the installation, but when it ends and restarts, turns staying with "e" logo fixed and nothing happens.

Comment: Luna is not offered for download because it is not supported.

Answer (score 1):

If you follow these steps (based on instructions from [the Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingKernelBoot)), you can see where Elementary OS is failing as it tries to start up:

1. Boot from the USB drive.
2. Navigate to "try Elementary OS," and press "e".
3. Remove the `quiet` and `splash` keywords (found in the line starting with `linux`). Also remove the parameter `vt.handoff=7`, and on the line that reads `set gfxpayload=$linux_gfx_mode`, replace with `set gfxpayload=text`.
4. Press "Ctrl+x" to boot.

What are the last few entries that appear when you try to boot in this mode?

What program are you using to create a bootable USB drive?

You are installing Elementary OS 0.3.2, right? This version fixes several installation issues from older versions.